# Eclipse Junit tab is getting passed every time while exceptions are there in Console tab

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, selenium-webdriver

> java.lang.AssertionError
>       at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
>       at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
>       at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
>       at com.bt.panorama.ip.widgets.trading.OrderStatus.verifyOrdersRange(OrderStatus.java:64)
>       at com.bt.panorama.ip.widgets.trading.OrderStatus.searchByDateRange(OrderStatus.java:49)
>
> ```
> > org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@class='mvc-orderstatuses']//tr[@class='no-results-row']"}
> ```
>
> Command duration or timeout: 10.11 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
>   System info: host: 'WV001768', ip: '10.13.12.184', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//div[@class='mvc-orderstatuses']//tr[@class='no-results-row']}
>   Session ID: e3ea478d-1150-44c9-81aa-ce73573ed864
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

While debugging I am able to see that an exception occurred and Error collector captured it.
Hence error collector should have print it in junit tab as printStackTrace() function is printing in console tab.

```
try
    {
        errList.add(error);
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)InstantiateDriver.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String folder = System.getProperty("browserType");
        if (folder == null)
        {
            folder = "firefox";
        }

        String dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").format(new Date()).trim();
        String envpath = System.getProperty("envpath");


        String imageFileDir;
        if (null == envpath)
        {
            imageFileDir = ".\\HTMLreport\\" + dt + "\\" + "html\\screenshots\\" + folder; // System.getProperty("selenium.screenshot.dir");
        }
        else
        {
            imageFileDir = ".\\HTMLreport\\" + dt + "\\" + envpath + "\\" + "html\\screenshots\\" + folder; 
        }

        File fle = new File(imageFileDir);
        if (!fle.exists())
        {
            fle.mkdirs();
        }

        if (imageFileDir == null)
            imageFileDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        try
        {
            String str = "";
            if (error.getMessage() != null)
                if (error.getMessage().length() > 10)
                    str = error.getMessage().substring(0, 10);
                else
                    str = error.getMessage().substring(0, error.getMessage().length() - 1);
            String methodname = error.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
            String className = error.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();
            StackTraceElement[] el = error.getStackTrace();
            for (int i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
            {
                if (el[i].getMethodName().startsWith("test"))
                {
                    methodname = el[i].getMethodName();
                    className = el[i].getClassName();
                    break;
                }

            }
            str = methodname + "_" + str;
            //eleminate '/' and spaces in the file name
            str = str.trim().replace("/", "-").replace(" ", "_").replace("'", "_").replace(":", "_");
            String fileName = str + "_" + (count++) + ".png";
            File file = new File(imageFileDir, fileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, file);

            String scRelativePath = "screenshots\\\\" + folder + "\\\\" + fileName;

            String errorString = error.getMessage();
            if (null != getExecMethod())
            {
                errorString = getExecMethod() + " : " + errorString;
            }
            String linkScreenShot = " - " + className + " # "
                + "<a escape=\"true\"  href=\"javascript:displayScreenshotLink(\'" + scRelativePath
                + "\');\">Click here for screenshot</a>";
            errorString = errorString + " " + linkScreenShot;
            if (error instanceof AssertionError)
                error = new AssertionError(errorString, error);

            else
                error = new Throwable(errorString, error);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.addError(error);
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at helpers.ErrorCollectorImpl.addError(ErrorCollectorImpl.java:85)
>       at com.bt.panorama.ip.tests.Trading.BusinessScenarios.ValidateOrder.testDuplicateOrderErrorMessage(ValidateOrder.java:52)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

this is exception regarding ErrorCollector its giving error where I am passing substring of error.getMessage().substring(0, 10)

Comment: Can you provide the code you use in your [tag:errorcollector]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there I just figured out that I had to use my own existing ErrorCollector class under @Rule annotation and what I have done is I have created one more object of java Errorcollector class on top of class which was getting override.